# Cambiar estilos a botones de paginación

Tags: laravel, blade, tailwind

estoy utilizando Laravel 8 y necesitaría hacer algunos ajustes en los botones de la paginación simple que provee Laravel, estoy utilizando simplePaginate y no se por donde habría que hacer esto, que de paso comento que es muy simple lo que necesito, solo quiero que haya un pequeño espacio entre los botones y poner un borde de otro color.

[image: Controles de Navegación]

Desde ya, muchas gracias y quedo a la espera de alguna respuesta.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar aquello que hayas intentado por favor?

Comment: Ok, había comenzado por posicionar mediante un div los botones de la siguiente manera:             <div class="mb-8 flex justify-end">
                {{$listdevisitas->links()}}
            </div>, Esto me presenta los botones a la derecha dentro del div, pero lo que quiero lograr es cambiar el borde de los botones y agregar un pequeño espacio entre ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes publicar los estilos de paginación que tiene laravel y editarlos, como lo deseas, solo tienes que ejecutar el comando:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

Luego de aplicar este comando en la línea de comandos tienes que ir a resource > view > vendor > pagination ahí es donde crean las vista del pagination.

En ese directorio te aparecerán las vistas de paginación que tienes, y puedes modificar la paginación como la requieres.

Ya para utilizarlo solo queda poner:

```
{{ $data->links(‘vendor.pagination.simplePaginate’) }}
```